# Can Array of function which are dependent be solved by reduce method of bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

Can anyone please clarify this reduce function of **`bluebird`** ...
How it works ? How to use this ??

I want this function work like `async.waterfall([ARRAY OF FUNCTIONS])`

```
"use strict";
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

Promise.reduce([function() {
        return 'Hardy';
    }, function(name) {
        console.log('0000' + name);
        return name + ' Jack';

    }, function(fullName) {
        console.log('000011' + fullName);
        return fullName + ' Danial';
    }],
    function(total, data) {
        console.log(total);
        console.log(data);
    }, 0).then(function(total) {

});
```

Expected Output :- **Hardy Jack Danial**

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `Promise.reduce`, but just the standard Array method:

```
[function() {
    return 'Hardy';
}, function(name) {
    console.log('0000' + name);
    return name + ' Jack';
}, function(fullName) {
    console.log('000011' + fullName);
    return fullName + ' Danial';
}].reduce(function(promise, fn) {
    return promise.then(fn);
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function(total) {
    console.log(total);
});
```

But really there's no point in using a `waterfall`-like array (literal!) of functions with promises. Just write out your chain:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return 'Hardy';
}).then(function(name) {
    console.log('0000' + name);
    return name + ' Jack';
}).then(function(fullName) {
    console.log('000011' + fullName);
    return fullName + ' Danial';
}).then(function(total) {
    console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: Unless the number of values/functions is variable, in which case [`mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) might come in handy.

Comment: @Tomalak I've never seen a use case with a variable array of functions. Sure, for an arbitrary array of values that should get processed by *one*  promise-returning function, there are multiple Bluebird solutions.

Comment: Speculative comment, I know. :)

Comment: can you just explain it's working .it would be very helpful.

Comment: @hardy It's just the 1:1 transformation of the second code snippet by using the `reduce` functionality. I assume you know how that works? Try expanding the `reduce` step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm so in love with async/await now, wanted to throw in a plug for how you would do this using it if your Javascript engine supports it and/or if you use Babel or webpack to transpile your source.

If you have 3 promises, `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, you can use the following syntax which is basically equivalent to async/waterfall except without all the functions with callbacks that gets bulky quick:

```
async function myAsyncAwaitWaterfallFunction() {
  try {
    const result1 = await p1
    const result2 = await p2
    const result3 = await p3

    return `${result1}_${result2}_${result3}`

  } catch (e) {
    doSomethingWithAPromiseRejection(e)
  }
}
```